# Echarts bar issues

Tags: bar-chart, echarts

I'm using `Echarts` in ordert to create some charts. 
My problem is that when I change the kind of chart from the `toolbox`, the new chart exceeds the plot area. I have this problem only for `bar`.

[image]

The chart is refreshed with a poller every second.

```
toolbox:
{
    show: true,
    feature:
    {
        magicType:
        {
            show: true,
            title:
            {
                line: "Line",
                bar: "Bar",
                tiled: "Tiled"
            },
            type: ["line", "bar", "tiled"]
        },
        restore:
        {
            show: true                
        },
        saveAsImage:
        {
            show: true
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the bars are placed *on* x axis ticks, instead of *in between* them.

This is probably caused by `boundaryGap: false`.

[Documentation on boundaryGap](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#xAxis.boundaryGap)

Try setting your x axis to:

```
xAxis: {
    boundaryGap : true,
}
```

---

If you do not want your labels to be in between the x axis ticks, use:

```
xAxis: {
    boundaryGap : true,
    xAxisTicks  : {
        alignWithLabel  : true
    }
}
```

[Documentation on alignWithLabel](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#xAxis.axisTick.alignWithLabel)